# Programmatically Lock workstation from Windows Service

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, windows-services

From my Windows Service, I'm trying to lock my Workstation using the below code:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool LockWorkStation();

if (!LockWorkStation()){
 //Workstation was unable to lock(Write this on event log)
}
```

but the above code is not working.

Anybody has a solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Windows service does not run on the desktop, so you can't call it from the service.

From the [LockWorkStation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376875(v=vs.85).aspx) documentation, **emphasis** mine:

> The LockWorkStation function is **callable only by processes running on the interactive desktop**. In addition, the user must be logged on, and the workstation cannot already be locked.

It might be a hack, but maybe you could create a tray application that can, in response to some sort of interprocess call from the service, call `LockWorkStation`.

If you don't like the visible nature of a tray application, consider creating a console application that spawns a thread to wait for the call, and runs windowless when the user logs in.

Another possibility is creating a Windows application that never creates a UI window. This is definitely what you want to do if you use the [data copy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms649009(v=vs.85).aspx) API.

The key here, is that *something* has to be running in the user's interactive context.

For reference, you can look at [Microsoft's MSDN topic on IPC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: is there any solution for this aside from creating a tray application? please give me a link if possible.

Comment: I updated my answer with another option. I don't think you can get away with spawning an application from the service, and if you can, it's going to likely be even more hackish as Antonio mentioned.

Comment: Just for clarification, can I call console application under the windows service?

Comment: You can call a console application or headless win32 process using some form of IPC. Search for "windows interprocess communication" to get some ideas. Something fancier would be a message bus or using sockets, but that may be overkill since you *know* the processes are on the same machine. You can do something super hackish like implement a file watcher in the console app that watches for the service to drop a file, but that's kinda clunky.

Comment: Probably not a console application, as they're visible.  (Even if you immediately hide the console, it still pops up briefly.)  They also use more resources.  Better to configure it as a Windows application, then just never create any windows.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it with the [WTSDisconnectSession](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383830(v=vs.85).aspx) Windows API, it will log out user in the same way LockWorkStation does.

However as the service is in a special session, you can't just disconnect WTS_CURRENT_SESSION and have to disconnect every active session on the computer.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class LockWorkstation
{
    [DllImport("wtsapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool WTSDisconnectSession(IntPtr hServer, int sessionId, bool bWait);

    [DllImport("wtsapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern int WTSEnumerateSessions(IntPtr hServer, int Reserved, int Version, ref IntPtr ppSessionInfo, ref int pCount);

    [DllImport("wtsapi32.dll")]
    static extern void WTSFreeMemory(IntPtr pMemory);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct WTS_SESSION_INFO
    {
        public Int32 SessionID;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
        public String pWinStationName;

        public WTS_CONNECTSTATE_CLASS State;
    }

    private enum WTS_INFO_CLASS
    {
        WTSInitialProgram,
        WTSApplicationName,
        WTSWorkingDirectory,
        WTSOEMId,
        WTSSessionId,
        WTSUserName,
        WTSWinStationName,
        WTSDomainName,
        WTSConnectState,
        WTSClientBuildNumber,
        WTSClientName,
        WTSClientDirectory,
        WTSClientProductId,
        WTSClientHardwareId,
        WTSClientAddress,
        WTSClientDisplay,
        WTSClientProtocolType
    }

    private enum WTS_CONNECTSTATE_CLASS
    {
        WTSActive,
        WTSConnected,
        WTSConnectQuery,
        WTSShadow,
        WTSDisconnected,
        WTSIdle,
        WTSListen,
        WTSReset,
        WTSDown,
        WTSInit
    }

    public static void LockWorkStation()
    {
        IntPtr ppSessionInfo = IntPtr.Zero;
        Int32 count = 0;
        Int32 retval = WTSEnumerateSessions(IntPtr.Zero, 0, 1, ref ppSessionInfo, ref count);
        Int32 dataSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(WTS_SESSION_INFO));
        IntPtr currentSession = ppSessionInfo;

        if (retval == 0) return;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            WTS_SESSION_INFO si = (WTS_SESSION_INFO)Marshal.PtrToStructure(currentSession, typeof(WTS_SESSION_INFO));
            if (si.State == WTS_CONNECTSTATE_CLASS.WTSActive) WTSDisconnectSession(IntPtr.Zero, si.SessionID, false);
            currentSession += dataSize;
        }
        WTSFreeMemory(ppSessionInfo);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this is the same as `Windows+L`?

Comment: @JobaDiniz This is the same as doing Windows+L on every opened session.

Comment: @mad Can we also unlock the system?

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that from Windows service, in clearly stated in [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa376875%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) that this API function only can be called from process running in interactive desktop. Windows services are not running in interactive desktop.

If you must do that you should first check if user is logged on and then spawn process under inpersonating user that you want to lock. But this seems to me as pretty hackish solution. Maybe a better solution would be launch hidden or tray application when user logs and then do the job from that application.

Comment: I am sorry if I did not mark yours as a correct answer, but I will give yours a vote.

Comment: Launching a process in the user's session to do work on your behalf is a pretty well-established technique.  I wouldn't call it a hack.  (There are several advantages over using an application that runs permanently in each user's session, the most important probably being that there's no really reliable way to do that.)

Comment: didn't mean that launching process in user session is a hack. I was talking about locking user session from service, will update my answer